# Job Configuration Object

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am implementing a new algorithm for scheduling in hadoop called `TaskTrackerAware Scheduler`. I have to configure some properties such as **mapred.tascheduler.task.max** ( maximum number of tasks that can run on a tasktracker for a single job) and **mapred.tascheduler.hosts** (host names of the task tracker in which jobs need to be run). How to configure these properties in Job configuration object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find below the snippet that may help you,

```
Configurarion conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("mapred.tascheduler.task.max" , <value>);
conf.set("mapred.tascheduler.hosts " ,   <value>);

Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "app name");
```

Let me know if you need any further help..

Comment: Thank you. That helped :)  Do you have any idea about configuring new schedulers in hadoop?

Comment: sorry, i dont have much idea about it.. yet I hope `mapreduce.jobtracker.taskscheduler` and `yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.class` properties might help you.